# turf-isobands doesn't work

Tags: turf

I am trying to use turf and turf-isobands. But it doesn't seemed to be included to turf.min.js. I downloaded turf-isobands-master.

```
 var isobands = turf.isobands(elLayer.toGeoJSON(), 'elevation', resolution, breaks);  # not working
 var isolines = turf.isolines(elLayer.toGeoJSON(), 'elevation', resolution, breaks);  # working
```

Do you have any ideas about why it is not working?

Comment: I have same problem. I couldn't find any code to load isobands module from turf.js. If you solved the problem, please let me know it.

Answer (score 1):

The [TurfJS changelog](https://github.com/Turfjs/turf/blob/393013ff3f24c71fb7dd9dac99435271d94c0e06/CHANGELOG.md#200) for version 2.0.0 says this:

> remove turf-isobands; use turf-isolines instead

There is also the [turf-isobands](https://github.com/Turfjs/turf-isobands) library, but I'm not sure if it works in a browser (if you need that).

Related Github issue [here](https://github.com/Turfjs/turf/issues/302), it was removed because of bugs.